# Count specific vowels in a sentence

Tags: python

I've found a few instances of this but my question is slightly different.

I need to scan a sentence like

```
For letter in sentence
if letter == "a" or letter == "A": letterATotal = letterATotal + 1
elif letter == "e" or letter == "E": letterETotal = letterETotal + 1
```

etc all the way to U. 
But then I need to compare them all and print the line containing the most frequent so
"the most frequent vowel is A occurring 5 times".
Problem is I don't know how to display the actual letter. I can only display the number.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> mystr = "AaAaaEeEiOoouuu"
>>> a,b = Counter(c for c in mystr.lower() if c in "aeiou").most_common(1)[0]
>>> "the most frequent vowel is {} occurring {} times".format(a.upper(), b)
'the most frequent vowel is A occurring 5 times'
>>>
```

Here is a reference on [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

---

**Edit:**

Here is a step-by-step demonstration of what's going on:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> mystr = "AaAaaEeEiOoouuu"
>>> Counter(c for c in mystr.lower() if c in "aeiou")
Counter({'a': 5, 'o': 3, 'e': 3, 'u': 3, 'i': 1})
>>> # Get the top three most common
>>> Counter(c for c in mystr.lower() if c in "aeiou").most_common(3)
[('a', 5), ('o', 3), ('e', 3)]
>>> # Get the most common
>>> Counter(c for c in mystr.lower() if c in "aeiou").most_common(1)
[('a', 5)]
>>> Counter(c for c in mystr.lower() if c in "aeiou").most_common(1)[0]
('a', 5)
>>> a,b = Counter(c for c in mystr.lower() if c in "aeiou").most_common(1)[0]
>>> a
'a'
>>> b
5
>>>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you this works perfectly! Can you explain how counter works for me? Especially the a,b = and the square brackets at the end.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - Yes, sorry about the delay.  I included a step-by-step demo in my post.

Comment: Can you explain the line (c for c in mystr.lower() if c in "aeiou")? Thanks

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - Sure.  That is a generator expression that gets only the vowels in `mystr`.  `mystr.lower()` returns a lowercase version of `mystr`.  `if c in "aeiou"` only gets `c` if it is a vowel (in this case, all the characters in `mystr` are vowels, so it isn't needed here.  I put it there for any other strings that contain non-vowels).

Comment: ahh! So `c` is just used inside the function. What does `c for c in mystr.lower()` mean?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - It means "character for each character in `mystr.lower()` (which is a lowercase version of `mystr`)".

Comment: Is there anyway to set the contents of the count(c for c...) to multiple variables so I can get more than the top 2 most common?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - Yea, you can do that with the `.most_common` method.  See my edit.

Comment: How to do you assign the .most_common method contents to different variables then? Like more than just a,b. So I can have say a,b,c,d,e,f and have them with the contents like in your example as a,5,o,3,e,3?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - That's not a very good idea because you'll need dynamic variables to hold the values.  In other words, there is no way to tell how many you will need before hand.  In this scenario, it would be best to just index the list returned by `.most_common`.

Comment: how do I index the list then? Or is there a better way to count vowels in a list and compare the value to display the top occuring.

Answer (score 2):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
for x in 'aaaeeeeeefffddd':
    if x.lower() in vowels:
        c[x.lower()] += 1
...         
>>> c
Counter({'e': 6, 'a': 3})
>>> letter, count = c.most_common()[0]
>>> letter, count
('e', 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code works if you are using Python 3 or above:

```
s = input ('Enter a word or sentence to find how many vowels:')

sub1 = 'a'
sub2 = 'e'
sub3 = 'i'
sub4 = 'o'
sub5 = 'u'

print ('The word you entered: ', s)

print ('The count for a: ', s.count(sub1))

print ('The count for e: ', s.count(sub2))

print ('The count for i: ', s.count(sub3))

print ('The count for o: ', s.count(sub4))

print ('The count for u: ', s.count(sub5))
```

Answer (score -2):

Substring through the sentence string, and increment an array of integers indexed 0-4 (for a-u)
at the end find the maximum value of the array and have it print the correct statement